# Gap between infill and walls for one filament only

Tags: filament, infill

When I'm printing with my Chromatik filament white, 1.75 mm in diameter, I observe a gap between the infill and the walls (see picture).

Everywhere on the web I can find explanations for this kind of problem (apparently it's the symptom of loose belts), but I have this problem for **this filament only**. I have the filaments Chromatik electric blue and Octofiber black and I don't have this issue with them. I tried to increase the temperature by ~10 °C, but it didn't have much effect.

Have you ever seen that guys? I repeat, it's with **this filament only**.

[image: Print showing infill and wall not touching]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have observed similar issues between walls, not necessarily between the infill and the walls.

It is most likely that the viscosity of this filament is way different (less fluid) than the other filaments you print. Not only mechanical issues (to be precise: inaccurate positioning e.g. caused by loose belts) could play a part in this, but also printing speed. A more viscous filament needs more pressure and time to get the filament through the nozzle. This is exactly what happened in my case, because of different wall speed line settings (inner and outer), the filament did not flow fast enough leading to under extrusion. In your case you probably also have a higher infill than wall speed, so lowering your infill speed may mitigate your problem. Also, most slicers have an option to define the overlap between the infill and the perimeters/walls, you could also increase that for this filament.

Comment: It makes sense. I decreased the inner wall speed (60 to 45 mm/s) and the infill speed (60 to 45). The outer wall speed is still 30 mm/s. Print temperature increased by 5 °C. The issue is totally fixed. I know there shouldn't be any reason to expect it, but still, I'm a bit surprised that for the same brand of filament print settings need to be so different.